# How does Redis Enterprise secure in-transit internal communications between its nodes?

Tags: encryption, redis

This page from Redislabs, titled: [Redis Enterprise: A Secure Database](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/technology/redis-security-reliability/) states the following:

```
Encryption | Data in transit | - Client<>Redis – SSL/TLS
           |                 | - Inter cluster (between cluster’s nodes) – IPSec
           |                 | - Across-cluster – SSL/TLS
```

It's unclear what Redislabs means when they state IPSec for the encryption of traffic among its own sub-components.

#### Question

- Do they do anything internal to facilitate this or do they expect that customers would set up a secure tunnel using some other product to secure this communications?

Comment: I suggest you direct this question to RedisLabs' support at support@redislabs.com

Comment: @ItamarHaber - I've done that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through this presentation from the VP of Redislabs, titled: [Secure Redis deployments for Simplified Compliance - HIPPA, PCI, GDPR | Redis Labs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhWmONUiXio) it would seem to be the case that Redis Enterprise does nothing to help secure the in-communications among its own nodes in a cluster.

[image: ss#1]

The product fully expects that customers utilize IPSec technologies such as:

- stunnel
- spiped
- strongswan
- iptables
- etc.

to encrypt/secure traffic however you deem necessary per your applications usage of Redis.

Answer (score -1):

Redis Enterprise comes with a deployment tool that allows securing inter-node communication using IPSec. As a result, the secured inter-node communication has practically no effect on cluster performance.

Oren

Comment: That's not correct, it provides no such capability.